# How to return an Observable Array instead of a subscription?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, observable

How can I make this forkJoin return an observable-array instead of a subscription?

```
connect(): Observable<any[]> {
this.userId = this.authService.userId;
this.habits$ = this.habitService.fetchAllById(this.userId);
this.status$ = this.statusService.fetchAll();
this.joined$ = forkJoin([
  this.habits$,
  this.status$
]).subscribe(([habits, statuses]) => {
  this.joined = habits.map(habit => ({
    ...statuses.find(t => t.habitId === habit.habitId),
    ...habits
  }));
});
return this.joined$;
```

}

At the moment my variables are defined like this:

```
export class HabitDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

  userId: Pick<User, 'id'>;
  habits$: Observable<Habit[]>;
  status$: Observable<Status[]>;
  joined$: Subscription;
  joined: any[];
```

But the connect() method needs an Observable-Array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I make this forkJoin return an observable-array instead of a subscription?

`forkJoin` DOES return array.  The reason you get a `Subscription` is because you are calling `.subscribe()`.

instead of doing your mapping logic inside subscribe, you can use the `map` operator:

```js
connect(): Observable<any[]> {
  this.userId  = this.authService.userId;
  this.habits$ = this.habitService.fetchAllById(this.userId);
  this.status$ = this.statusService.fetchAll();
  
  return forkJoin([this.habits$, this.status$]).pipe(
    map(([habits, statuses]) =>
      habits.map(habit => ({
        ...habit,
        status: statuses.find(s => s.habitId === habit.habitId)
      }))
    )
  );
}
```